# d3 Stack - Linear Scale for X-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In all the examples I've come across so far, (like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208), [this](https://bl.ocks.org/DimsumPanda/689368252f55179e12185e13c5ed1fee) or [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mstanaland/6100713)) I see stacked charts in d3 have an ordinal scale. I presume this is because stacked charts are considered an extension of bar charts which are generally of ordinal scale on the one of the axis.

In my case, using sample data

```
{"a":[20,10],"b":[50,0],"c":[45,60],"d":[10,40]}
```

I need to generate a stacked chart with a linear scale x-axis like below.

[image: Stack chart (or is it one?)]

(The width of each column is a scale of the sum of 2 elements of the array, and the 2 cells in each column represent the values of the array elements as a % of the height. The columns are sorted left to right on sum desc)

I tried to use `d3.stack` to generate such a chart using the below code, but this seems a little messy to me, as I'm accessing the `data` object of the stack array.

```js
var body = d3.select('body');
var svg = body.append('svg').attr('height',200).attr('width',500);
var maing = svg.append('g');

var inputData = JSON.parse('{"a":[20,10],"b":[50,0],"c":[45,60],"d":[10,40]}')

// generate class
var colors = d3.schemeCategory10
var mysheet = document.styleSheets[0];

Object.keys(inputData).forEach(function(d,i){
  mysheet.insertRule(`.${d}{fill:${colors[i]}; opacity:0.8}`);
  mysheet.insertRule(`.${d}_h{fill:${colors[i]}; opacity:0.6}`);
});

// convert to flattened array
var vals = Array("p", "h");
var cumT = +0
var transformedData = Object.keys(inputData).map(function(d,i){
  let o = {}; o.mp = d;
  inputData[d].forEach(function(d,i){o[vals[i]]=d})
  o.t=o.p+o.h;
  return o;
}).sort(function(a,b){
  return b.t - a.t
}).map(function(d,i){
  let o = d; o.cumT = cumT += d.t
  return o;
})

var stack = d3.stack().keys(vals);
var stackData = stack(transformedData);

var g = maing.selectAll('g')
  .data(stackData).enter().append('g')

var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,230]).range([0,100])  // TODO: use d3.max here
var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,1]).range([0,140])    // some predefined height

g.selectAll('rect').data(function(d){return d})
  .enter().append('rect')
  .attr('x', function(d,i){return x(d.data.cumT-d.data.t)})
  .attr('y', function(d,i){return y(d[0]/d.data.t)})
  .attr('width', function(d,i){return x(d.data.t)})
  .attr('height', function(d,i){return y((d[1]-d[0])/d.data.t) })
  //.style('stroke-width', 1).style('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('class', function(d){
    return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().key === "p" ? d.data.mp : d.data.mp+"_h";
  })
;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stack Dev</title>
    <style media="screen">

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What would be a better way to go about generating something like this? Especially if I have to generate many many small charts like this on a single page?

Comment: As you have a **perfect working code** here, I suggest you post this at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you do so, please mark it with the `d3.js` tag, and I'll have a look at it. However, *"messy"* is pretty much opinion-based: it may turn out that your code right now is the best one.

Comment: Anyone voting to close this- please don't use CR as a reason, use a reason like _too broad_.

Comment: @SamOnela I'm the one who voted to close suggesting the migration to Code Review. This is not too broad: OP has already a working code, they are just asking if using a stack generator is the best option. It would be too broad if they just ask us to create the chart, without providing their solution using the stack generator.

Comment: I see "_What would be a better way to go about generating something like this?_" ... that sounds like a subjective question that could attract diverse (and also _opinionated_) answers...

Comment: And that's exactly why I suggested the migration to Code Review: opinionated answers are frowned upon **here**, but are perfectly on-topic **there**.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Sure- the issue isn't that it was suggested to migrate there, the issue is that that was the reason for closing. Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SamOnela Fair enough, I retracted my vote.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @GerardoFurtado and SamOnela. I'm new to both d3.js and Stackoverflow. So, I really appreciate the guidance. I've created an item in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180803/d3-stack-with-linear-x-axis).